# Bluetooth from a webpage

Tags: java, javascript, bluetooth

Is it possible to have JavaScript which calls a Java file (or something of the sort), so we can connect to a Bluetooth device and send it commands from a web page?

If it is possible, what are some ideas behind it that I can use to get it working?

Sorry for my poor language, I am not really sure how to word it.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+bluetooth ?

Comment: The name of this question is really poor, makes it look like the question is about JavaScript and Java when it's really about how to connect to Bluetooth from a web page

Comment: I was planning to use Java but then changed the question, forgot to change the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java can be used to send files via Bluetooth, and there is a tutorial on it at http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/07/27/bluetooth.html

You could run a Java applet from the web browser that would use Bluetooth, although it would probably come up with a warning asking if you want to give the applet access to the files on your computer. JavaScript, however, would not be necessary, since an applet can run directly on a webpage.